# Как исправить ошибку FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-default-executor-0?

Tags: java, android, исключения

Пишу андроид приложение и у меня возникла такая ошибка при добавлении на firestore обєкта

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-default-executor-0
Process: com.app.cyb, PID: 1132
java.lang.AssertionError
at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.getResourceResolver(DnsNameResolver.java:536)
at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.access$500(DnsNameResolver.java:60)
at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:211)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 5715
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 3867209
D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=5715, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=TrainAddActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-5860237179272852510}]
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1132 SIG: 9

Вот метод в котором она возникает:

```
private void addElInFireStoreDB(Train train){
    firebaseFirestore.collection("train").add(train)
            .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> {
                Controller.showDialogMessage(this, "Successful added");
            }).addOnFailureListener(documentReference ->{
                Controller.showDialogMessage(this, "Failure adding");
    });
}
```

Вот мои зависимости:

```java
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Нужно просто было изменить версию firestore зависимостей.

```java
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```